# 2 phase commit data consistency when one node crashes or is slow during commit phase

Tags: database, transactions, distributed-transactions, xa, 2phase-commit

In 2 phase commit, lets say one of the nodes crashes or is slow during the commit phase and the other nodes have already successfully committed their changes. Now if a query is issued to one of those successful nodes, what will be its data consistency as visible from the client perspective?

Does the client see the latest committed changes on that successful node or does the transaction coordinator pass the previous successful TransactionID along with the query to the node so that the client can only see the data/state prior to the current ongoing transaction?